# encounter difficulties on how to get value on array

Tags: php

Here is my problem how can i get the `array[1]`
i have an foreach on my view  i can't get the value of `[1] => Array?`

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [details] => Array
                    (
                        [product_id] => 1
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [field_name] => çŠ¬ç¨®
                                [field] => ãƒšã‚­ãƒ‹ãƒ¼ã‚º
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [field_name] => ç”Ÿå¹´æœˆæ—¥
                                [field] => 2013å¹´12æœˆ13æ—¥
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [field_name] => æ€§åˆ¥
                                [field] => ãƒ¡ã‚¹
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [field_name] => ä¾¡æ ¼
                                [field] => Â¥98,000
                            )

                    )

                [image] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [filename] => 1394462124.jpg
                                [0] => 1394462124.jpg
                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [details] => Array
                    (
                        [product_id] => 2
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [field_name] => çŠ¬ç¨®
                                [field] => ãƒšã‚­ãƒ‹ãƒ¼ã‚º
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [field_name] => ç”Ÿå¹´æœˆæ—¥
                                [field] => 2013å¹´12æœˆ13æ—¥
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [field_name] => æ€§åˆ¥
                                [field] => ã‚ªã‚¹
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [field_name] => ä¾¡æ ¼
                                [field] => Â¥88,000
                            )

                    )

                [image] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [filename] => 1394462181.jpg
                                [0] => 1394462181.jpg
                            )

                    )

            )
```

i will fetch the  [1] => Array inside the 
i can't get the `[1] => Array` using foreach on my view what is can i get the value on `array[1]`

Comment: Can you add your `foreach` loop to the code above, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to loop through and deal with each dataset, the following code will do that:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $data) {
    // Output data
    // The first row will be $arr[0], and the second $arr[1], etc…
}
```

-- Original answer

Assuming you mean the second array within the top-level array and that you *only* want to access the second element in that array (index 1), you should just be able to access it as follows:

```
$arr[1]
```

eg:

```
$second_photo = $arr[1];
```

Where `$arr` is the variable name you've assigned to the array you've `var_dump()`ed above.

That said, your question is ambiguous and not very clear. Can you please provide more information as to what you are actually trying to achieve? (Loop though and display all instances, for example?)